# Interval of convergence of $\sum_{n=4}^\infty x^n/n^5$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, summation

> Find the interval of convergence $$\sum_{n=4}^\infty x^n/n^5$$

I'm lost here. My intuition was to use the ratio test.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)^5} \times  \frac{n^5}{x^n} $$

However this is what I get.

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{xn^5}{(n+1)^5} $$

Any thoughts?

Comment: I think you want $n \to \infty$ in the last limit...

Comment: yeah thank you.. haha my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. Note that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{n^5}{(n+1)^5} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac1{\left(1+\dfrac1n\right)^5} = 1$$
Hence, we can conclude that the series converges for $\vert x \vert < 1$. Also, we know that it converges for $x = \pm 1$. (Why?) and hence the series converges for $\vert x \vert \leq 1$.

Comment: I knew the limit went to 1 :\ I just thought the ratio test was inconclusive at 1.

Comment: For power series, the radius of convergence always holds for $|x|$ inside the radius of convergence, but you have to check $|x|$ ON the radius of convergence, here $\pm 1$. Marvis is prompting you to justify why, here, it does converge at $\pm 1$, and hence for $|x| \leq 1$.

Comment: I hope you don't mind, @Marvis, that I've "chimed in" below your post.

Comment: @amWhy Not at all!

Comment: @amWhy Would stating that the series converges at 1 be sufficient to prove it's convergence? And it's interval being, $$(-\infty,1]$$

Comment: it's interval of convergence is $[-1, 1]$. If you can show it converges at x = 1 and x = -1, then you're done.

Comment: How should I go about showing that convergence?

Comment: @RyanDawkins: the p-test or the integral test. Either shows that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^p}$ converges for $p>1$.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Theoretical_radius), the radius of convergence is
$$
\frac1{\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}|a_n|^{1/n}}
$$
In this case, $a_n=\dfrac1{n^5}$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n^{5/n}=1$, therefore, the radius of convergence is $1$.

Comment: Is there a way to show this without using the root test?

Comment: @RyanDawkins: This formula always works, but in special cases, as with the series in your question, the ratio test works, too (Marvis showed this).

Comment: That's the test I appealed to as well, in an earlier post +1